# When to use AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, web-applications

I want to develop a website by my own. I want to make different web applications which need to interact with databases. I read about AngularJS, a JavaScript framework. The thing I do not understand is: When to use AngularJS? Do I first build my website in HTML & CSS and then add functionality to it with AngularJS? How do professional developers start with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep reading the documentation / tutorials of AngularJS, it will help you understand it.

Comment: @SinDeus Yes I will do. I hoped I could get a clear answer before investing to much time in something unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular js is a javascript frame work which will run at client side.

- It will reduce no. of http calls to the server.
- Lot of server side executions can be done at the client side itself.
- Page loading is faster.
- Mainly used for single page applications.
- Used to write modular and re-usable code.
- If you want to create some kind of social interaction site which have likes, comments, posts etc in that scenario Angular js is best choice.
- You can use Angular js along with lot of server side languages like Php, Asp .net etc.

Comment: Okay, so is it also standard today to use Html, Css, Ja aScript and jQuery? Or is it obsolete?

Comment: Jquery is just a library for memory management and effective Dom manipulation angular js is very useful  it has databinding.

Answer (score 8):

When you want:

1. A single page app
2. A RESTFUL app
3. Flexibility of the front end and Ultimate separation of both front and back end

And you should stay away from it when:

1. you have low budget as you will need both front and backend engineers. Most times, backend engineers can bring up your site without worrying too much about various stuffs Javascript has to offer.

If mobile users are you main target developing HTML5 Mobile application. I prefer Backbone instead (Yes backbone)because Angular makes my phone extremely hot and drains battery like hell.

Comment: well someone got it right